# How to make text with gradient between two colors?

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to recreate an effect where there is one color on the two extreme sides of the text and another in the center.

The only method I know of is setFill but obviously it fills the text with a single color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to just show you what @James_D already mentioned.

You can set both linear & radial gradients to the text. But you need to keep in mind that the difference in linear vs radial gradients on `Text` will not be as effective as on the normal `Region`/`Rectangle`. They will look like similar with a little difference. So you need to play with the radial gradient parameters for  desired effect.

```
Text text1 = new Text("Resourceful");
text1.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 50px; -fx-fill:linear-gradient(to right, red, blue, red);");

Text text2 = new Text("Resourceful");
text2.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 50px; -fx-fill:radial-gradient(focus-distance 0% , center 50% 50% , radius 50% , blue, red);");
```

[image]

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark the answer provided by @James_D as correct answer. This answer is just a supportive information to that answer.

Answer (score 3):

> `setFill(...)` ... obviously it fills the text with a single color

It is not clear where you get that information from. According to the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Paint)), `setFill()` takes any kind of [`Paint`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Paint.html) object, which would include both [linear gradients](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html) and [radial gradients](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/RadialGradient.html); it is not limited to `Color` instances.

Just use `setFill(...)` with an appropriate gradient.